# Forcing CodeIgniter to show 404 page instead of any other error like 1064

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, http-status-code-404

How can replace error pages like

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL     server version for the right syntax to use near 'order by rand()' at line 1
```

with my website's default 404 error page?

Comment: The best solution is to ensure that you sql is valid, a production site should not be throwing database query errors

Comment: What you are saying is to put define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production'); in index.php . I have already done that, but the site is showing these kinds of error.

Comment: You should not be using 404 to cover up DB errors. If you prefer to not show the error, edit the file located at `application/errors/error_db.php` to make sure that no specific details are displayed.

Comment: @dakdad Thanks, I did that. Actualy the site is live now, so I don't want visiters to see any database/php error. I thought setting ('ENVIRONMENT', 'production') would works but it isn't doig the job.

Comment: this may helpfull ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14235886/codeigniter-catch-database-errors

Comment: Also, I noticed that you're showing results randomly. That's really a BAD practice!

If your table has a couple of thousands of entries, you'll see how slow it will get because ORDER BY RAND() has a running time of N*log(N) whereas other approaches are nearly constant. 

This post can further elaborate on optimizing `order by rand()` 
http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/

Comment: The solution is found at here. Click [stackoverflow.com][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236768/codeigniter-php-forcing-a-404/4022063#4022063

Answer (score 18):

You can force 404 with the method

```
show_404();
```

This will show 404 when u want it. In your case just catch your error and use this function.

Or you can set custom error handler, log it and display 404, thought i wouldn't recommend doing that.